# Why I can't subclass

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to subclass PersistentDictionary, but compiler marks **base(storage_key)** and says :

```
Error   1   'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

This is my code:

```
public class MyPersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        private string storage_key;

        public MyPersistentDictionary(string storage_key):base(storage_key)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization

            this.storage_key = storage_key;
        }
    }
```

And I am sure **PersistentDictionary**  has a constructor with one string :
https://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EsentCollections/PersistentDictionary.cs

Comment: Error clearly says that 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. By object compiler means that `PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. What is that `PersistentDictionary`? Did you checked its documentation?

Comment: Which part of the error message you don't understand? `PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't have a constructor that takes a string. I would guess you don't need to pass `storage_key` to base constructor, and `base:(storage_key)` can be removed completely.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It has such a constructor : https://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EsentCollections/PersistentDictionary.cs

Comment: You can't inherit a `sealed` class which is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [type](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EsentCollections/PersistentDictionary.cs) you are trying to subclass is [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) so no types may inherit.

```
public sealed partial class PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : 
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDisposable
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
```

You can of course get around this issue by taking an instance as a parameter.

```
public sealed class PersistentCache<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _backingInstance;

    public PersistentCache(PersistentDictionary<TKey, TValue> backingInstance)
    {
        _backingInstance = backingInstance;    
    }

    // implement IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
}
```

Comment: So I implement all methods?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi - You don't have to but I recommend it.